# Send e mails from localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

I want to send emails from **localhost**, without using a domain. using **php xampp**. is there a any possible way of doing it?

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xxx@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail("xxx@gmail.com", "subject", "body", $headers);
```

Comment: you will need to have a mail server running on your local

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, install Sendmail or Postfix in your system. Or in Windows use this software : http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to make sure that these values are not commented in your php.ini file. To uncomment, simply remove the `;` at the start of the line

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

Then you need to start 'Mercury Mail' from you XAMPP control panel. Once it's running, you can try sending your email.