# Send email from localhost to smtp

Tags: php, smtp

i am trying to send the contact form data to email using smtp server . but its not working and i dont know how to configure smtp, i googled it but didn't found any good solution. my php code for email sending is :

```
    // Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.example.com.
        ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");

        // Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
        ini_set("smtp_port","465");

        // Please specify the return address to use
        ini_set("sendmail_from","chadhar313@gmail.com>");

        $to ="chadhar313@yahoo.com";

        $yourname = trim($_POST['yourname']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);

        $header = "Contact Form";

        $message = "Name: $yourname \r\n Email: $email \r\n Subject:  
    $subject \r\n Message: $message";

        $headers = "From:" . $yourname;
        $mailsent = mail($to, $header, $message, $headers);

        if($mailsent) {
            $sent = true;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send e mails from localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771854/send-e-mails-from-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP must be configured correctly in the `php.ini` file with the details of how your system sends email. Open `php.ini` file available in the `/etc/` directory and find the section headed `[mail function]`.

Windows users should ensure that two directives are supplied. The first is called `SMTP` that defines your email server address. The second is called `sendmail_from` which defines your own email address.

The configuration for Windows should look something like this:

> [mail function] ; For Win32 only. SMTP = smtp.secureserver.net
>
> ; For win32 only sendmail_from = webmaster@tutorialspoint.com